# Null pointer exception while using getRow() in jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have written a java code using JXL api to read data from excel & return the table in form of 2D array. I'm getting a null pointer exception while using getRow()
My Code is as follows,

```
public String[][] getExcelData(String xlPath, String shtName)throws Exception 
{
    int ci,cj;

    Workbook workbk = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(xlPath));
    Sheet sht = workbk.getSheet(0);


    Cell Start = sht.findCell("Start");
    System.out.println("Start cell found");
    Cell End = sht.findCell("End");

    int startRow = Start.getRow();
    System.out.println("start row number"+startRow);
    int endRow = End.getRow();

    int startColumn = Start.getColumn();
    int endColumn = End.getColumn();

    /*rowCount = sht.getRows();
    colCount = sht.getColumns();*/
    int tableStartRow = startRow+1;
    int tableStartColumn = startColumn+1;

    int tableEndRow = endRow-1;
    int tableEndColumn = endColumn-1;

    //tabArray = new String[rowCount-1][colCount];
    tabArray = new String[tableEndRow-1][tableEndColumn-1];
    System.out.println("#row: " + rowCount);
    System.out.println("#col: " + colCount);

    ci=0;

    for (int i=1;i<=tableEndRow-1;i++, ci++)
    {             

        cj=0;

        for (int j=1;j<=tableEndColumn-1;j++, cj++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ci ->"+ci+" & Cj ->"+cj);
            System.out.println("i ->"+i+" & j ->"+j);
            System.out.println("contents"+sht.getCell(j, i).getContents());
            tabArray[ci][cj]= sht.getCell(j, i).getContents();

            System.out.println("Value at"+ci+""+cj+"is ->"+tabArray[ci][cj]+"\n");

        }
   }
   return (tabArray);
}



Start cell found
SKIPPED: Test
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider        MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at DataProvider.DataSource.getExcelData(DataSource.java:39)
at DataProvider.DataSource.getLoginData(DataSource.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider    (MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
... 20 more
```

The excel to be read is -
[image]

Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: Try to follow Java Naming Conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is  spaces in your mastersheet in cell where  "Start" is written. Remove extra space after/before  Start.
It will work.